# npm start says can not find 'semver'

Tags: 22.04, npm

[image]npm start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:

- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object. (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
  '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js',
  '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
  }

Comment: [Have you tried …](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597057)

Comment: yes. but it didn't fix the issue. that's why asked my own question with a screenshot

Comment: It may be worthwhile to explain things you’ve done so that people like me don’t waste your time asking about things you’ve already attempted 